# How to configure Webpack to bundle global scope typescript functions along side module exported functions?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have to integrate global functions from another project I just want to test quickly, I'm new to Webpack and only used it with exported module so I can't see how to do this.

As said here [https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#:~:text=In%20TypeScript%2C%20just%20as%20in%20ECMAScript%202015%2C%20any,global%20scope%20%28and%20therefore%20to%20modules%20as%20well%29](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#:%7E:text=In%20TypeScript%2C%20just%20as%20in%20ECMAScript%202015%2C%20any,global%20scope%20%28and%20therefore%20to%20modules%20as%20well%29).

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

I tried something like this but it doesn't work :

```
  entry: {
    main: './src/main/*.ts', 
  },
```

Comment: It's here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/ . Good luck with that.